# background-position in explorer 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

i have a problem with positioning body background. It goes like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--body id="body" style="
        text-align:center;
        background-color:#031a43;
        background-image : url('design/bgFrontPage.jpg');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position: top center;" //-->
</script>
```

works just fine in all browsers except IE 9 where the bg moves to the left.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with Firebug?

Comment: Your code is strange enough already. Are you sure the JS parser accepts CSS?

Answer (score 0):

very strange.

I try this code in my page:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .bg
        {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #031a43;
            background-image: url('Styles/166894621.jpg');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: top center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="bg">
</body>
```

Background image located in center.

Answer (score 0):

I hope IE9/any can be rendered as IE8 by adding below line of meta in the head of html

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"/>
```

Comment: That's a stopgap solution for existing sites that break. Using it proactively on new content is a bad idea.